# Numpy vectorization of mathematical equation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I wrote equation [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y80c8.png] with for loops:

```
A = np.random.rand(10, 100)
B = np.random.rand(100, 100)
c = np.random.rand(100)

@timeit
def operate_loops(X, W, b):
  y1 = 0
  y2 = 0
  y3 = 0
  l1 = 0
  l2 = 0
  for j in range(np.shape(X)[0]):
      for n in range(np.shape(W)[1]):
          for m in range(np.shape(W)[0]):
              y1=y1+X[j][m] * W[m][n]
          y2=y2+y1+b[n]
      y3=y3+y2

  return y3
```

Now I want to write this equation as numpy vectorized code, without use of loops. I do first summation [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGmHc.png] like:

```
np.sum(x[0,:]*w[:,0])
```

but I don't have a clue how to other sigma summations without looping

Comment: Please add input and expected output... Also any code you have will be useful (even if is using for-loops).

Comment: You should include what have you tried

Comment: $\Sigma_m$ X_{i,m} . W_{m,n} is just the matrix multiplication i.e  X@W

Comment: @Dariusz Majcherczyk BTW, your operate_loops function is incorrect.

Comment: Isn't $\Sigma_m$ X_{i,m} . W_{m,n} only (0,0) entry of multiplication result matrix?

Comment: $\Sigma_m X_{i,m} . W_{m,n} $ is (i,n) the element of product of X and W matrices.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252283/definition-of-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your equation translates to following

```
y = np.sum(X@W) + X.shape[0]*np.sum(b)
```

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

[Murali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10289025/murali)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69506340/2749397) is correct but a little bit overcomplicated (please everyone, trust broadcasting)

My simpler proposal is

```
y = np.sum(X@W+b)
```

and here it's a small example of its application

```
In [20]: import numpy as np
    ...: X, W, b = np.ones((3,7)), np.ones((7,4)), np.arange(1,5)
    ...: print(b)
    ...: print(X@W)
    ...: print(X@W+b)
    ...: print((8+9+10+11)*3)
    ...: print(np.sum(X@W) + X.shape[0]*np.sum(b)) # Murali's proposal
[1 2 3 4]
[[7. 7. 7. 7.]
 [7. 7. 7. 7.]
 [7. 7. 7. 7.]]
[[ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
 [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
 [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]]
114
114.0

In [21]: print(y:=np.sum(X@W+b))
114.0
```

Comment: Should't we add nth element of b vector every time we do ∑n summation?

Comment: Why is this solution not giving the same result as my operate_loops function?

Comment: @DariuszMajcherczyk (1) no, the meaning of `A_mn + B_n` is a matrix where each row, of length `N`, is summed term by term with the vector `B` also of length N (2) I haven't investigated but possibly it's a disagreement on how `B` must be summed.

Answer (score 0):

Proper answer was : `y = np.sum(X@W) + X.shape[0]*np.sum(b)` (more clear for me)
or : `y = np.sum(X@W+b)`

My operate_loops function was bad because I misunderstood the equation meaning. Comment of gboffi helped me understand it:

> the meaning of A_mn + B_n is a matrix where each row, of length N, is summed term by term with the vector B also of length N.

My new proper operate_loops function is:

```
 def operate_loops(X, W, b):
    y1 = 0
    for j in range(np.shape(X)[0]):
        for n in range(np.shape(W)[1]):
            for m in range(np.shape(W)[0]):
                y1 = y1 + X[j][m] * W[m][n]
            y1=y1+b[n]
    return y1
```